Automatic deleting of OTP
I am trying to create a function that automatically deletes OTP that are expired in FastAPI.
I tried this:
 @app.on_event('startup')
@repeat_every(seconds=300)
async def delete_expired_otp(db: db_dependency):
    print("deleting")
    expired_otp = db.query(OTPModel).filter(OTPModel.expires_at < datetime.utcnow()).all()
    if expired_otp:
        for otp in expired_otp:
            db.delete(otp)
            db.commit()
    print("deleted")

I even changed the filter to be is_used to be true, but that didn't change anything.

slightly offtopic, but why do you care? Cleaning up once a day/week/month/quarter/year should be good enough. If an OTP is valid, is a check you (should) do when the OTP is used.

Have you looked at Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database? If so add the relevant log entries if not then go look now and then return the relevant entries.

What you're doing is entirely unnecessary. OTPs can be constructed from a HMAC, which means they can have a declared and unforgeable expiration date built right into them, so your system just needs to verify the HMAC/signature and expiration when it's actually used - which means there is absolutely zero security risk or danger from having expired OTPs lying around (unless someone invents a time-machine, I guess?)

Please see [mre] and add sufficient details (table DDL, sample data, and expected results). Why are you deleting expired rows one-by-one instead of deleting them with a single statement with appropriate criteria?

thanks i didn't realize they was so much option to consider going about this
